# Magento 2.4.5 - ACL for Menu and Configuration!

Tags: acl, system-configuration, adminmenu, magento2.4.5

**How to use ACL for Menus and Configuration in Magento 2.4.5 ?**

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps -

1. Create menu.xml

```
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
        <menu>
         <add id="Certification_ACL::menu" title="Custom Menu" module="Certification_ACL" sortOrder="10" resource="Certification_ACL::menu"/>
         <add id="Certification_ACL::create" title="Create" module="Certification_ACL" sortOrder="10" parent="Certification_ACL::menu" action="acl/create/index" resource="Certification_ACL::create"/>
         <add id="Certification_ACL::delete" title="Delete" module="Certification_ACL" sortOrder="20" parent="Certification_ACL::menu" action="acl/delete/index" resource="Certification_ACL::delete"/>
         <add id="Certification_ACL::view" title="View" module="Certification_ACL" sortOrder="30" parent="Certification_ACL::menu" action="acl/view/index" resource="Certification_ACL::view"/>
        </menu>
    </config>
```

1. Create system.xml -

```
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
  <system>
    <tab id="custom_acl_tab" translate="label" sortOrder="300">
        <label>Custom ACL Tab</label>
    </tab>
    <section id="custom_acl_section" translate="label" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <label>Custom ACL Section</label>
        <tab>custom_acl_tab</tab>
        <resource>Certification_ACL::config</resource>
        <group id="custom_acl_group" translate="label" type="text" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Custom ACL Group</label>
            <field id="custom_acl_field" translate="label" type="select" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Custom ACL Field</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
            </field>
        </group>
    </section>
</system>
```

3. And finally, create acl.xml -

   ```
       <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
          <acl>
            <resources>
               <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                  <resource id="Certification_ACL::menu" title="Custom Menu" sortOrder="10" >
                     <resource id="Certification_ACL::create" title="Create" sortOrder="50" />
                     <resource id="Certification_ACL::delete" title="Delete" sortOrder="100" />
                     <resource id="Certification_ACL::view" title="View" sortOrder="150">
                        <resource id="Certification_ACL::view_additional" title="View Additional Information" sortOrder="10" />
                     </resource>
                  </resource>

                   <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores">
                           <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores_settings">
                               <resource id="Magento_Config::config">
                                   <resource id="Certification_ACL::config" title="Custom ACL Configuration"/>
                               </resource>
                           </resource>
                    </resource>

               </resource>
            </resources>
          </acl>
       </config>
   ```

Note - Don't forget to include `<?xml version="1.0"?>` at the very first line of each of the .xml file.